# How to mock/stub/shim SerialPort.GetPortNames()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, serial-port, shim

I'm trying to test an ApiController class in C#, specifically a function that uses SerialPort.GetPortNames(). what this returns depends on the machine it is run on, So I'd like to be able to Shim/stub/mock it in some way to have it return dummy data.

using visual studio 2015, project targets .net 4.5.2, and using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

I think Microsoft Fakes would be able to do exactly what I need, but I do not have Visual Studio Enterprise.

I've learned that Moq is worthless here, and pose doesn't work with the version of .Net the project is targeting (4.5.2).

I've looked into prig, but I have no idea how to configure it for anything besides datetime.now().

and I don't understand how to actually test using Smock.

```cs
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("PortList")]
        public HttpResponseMessage SerialPortList()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            try
            {
                List<string> Ports = new List<string>(SerialPort.GetPortNames());
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Ports);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
            }
            return response;
        }
```

I want to be able to shim (right word?) the static method from SerialPort, and have it return a dummy list of serial ports (["COM1","COM2"]).

Comment: Mocking/shim has become a religion of questionable benefit for the majority of use cases.  Because the code you are testing is not the same as the real system, your tests have zero contribution as to reporting how healthy your system is come UAT/PROD time.   In your case, mocking is only useful if your computer has no serial ports, which is unlikely as Windows still represents some devices (USB comes to mind) via logical serial ports even if you don’t have say a physical DE-9 socket on your motherboard

Comment: I had to use software to have usb appear as serial ports on my machine. if I disconnect the USB's connecting to another device, I have 0 serial ports.

Comment: USBs are physically connected to your motherboard and can’t be removed

Comment: I mean the USB plugs connected to the ports. The USB ports aren't seen as serial ports. I have a driver from Benfei that came with a serial port to USB cable, and when I connect another machine to my machine (like my cell phone or another computer), it appears as a serial port that is called when I use SerialPort.GetPortNames().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I get around mocking static methods like `SerialPort.GetPortNames` is to add a layer of indirection. The simplest way in your case is to create a `SerialPortList` overload that accepts a `Func<string[]>` like so.

```cs
public HttpResponseMessage SerialPortList()
{
    return SerialPortList(SerialPort.GetPortNames);
}

public HttpResponseMessage SerialPortList(Func<string[]> getPortNames)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    try
    {
        List<string> Ports = new List<string>(getPortNames());
        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Ports);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
    }
    return response;
}
```

in your unit test...

```cs
public void Test()
{
    var portNames = new[] { "COM1" };
    foo.SerialPortList(() => portNames);
}
```